# Is there a list of all possible PHP imap_last_error() messages?

Tags: php, imap

imap_last_error() gives a string return in PHP when an error has occured.

I'd like to capture these so I can pass them to my app and act upon them. Problem is, it doesn't give a error code, additionally I can't find all the possible errors of which may appear.

Does anyone know where I can discover these? Currently I know

```
'Unknown Error',
'Too many login failures',
'Login aborted'
```

but there must be more.

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download the [UW c-client](http://www.washington.edu/imap/) and check the file `c-client\imap4r1.c`.

The great majority of the error messages are reproductions of the error messages the IMAP server has sent. I found a few that were predetermined, though. Here they are:

```
mm_log ("Scan not valid on this IMAP server",ERROR);
mm_log ("Unable to negotiate TLS with this server",ERROR);
mm_log ("IMAP Authentication cancelled",ERROR);
mm_log ("Can't do secure authentication with this server",ERROR);
mm_log ("Server disables LOGIN, no recognized SASL authenticator",ERROR);
mm_log ("Can't do /authuser with this server",ERROR);
mm_log ("Too many login failures",ERROR);
mm_log ("Login aborted",ERROR);
mm_log ("[NOTUIDPLUS] Can't do UID EXPUNGE with this server",ERROR);
mm_log ("Excessively complex sequence",ERROR);
mm_log ("Can't access server for append",ERROR);
mm_log ("ACL not available on this IMAP server",ERROR);
mm_log ("Quota not available on this IMAP server",ERROR);
```